# Unable to get basic JMockit test working

Tags: jmockit

This is my first attempt at using jmockit. I have a gradle project (spring boot). Ensured that jmockit is the first in test classpath.

```
compile "net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.4.5"

testCompile "org.jmockit:jmockit:1.8"
testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
```

And then I want to fake a `TranslatorFactory` such that it returns a fake `Translator`.

TranslatorFactory class is something like

```
public class TranslatorFactory {
  public ArgTranslator getTranslator(Class<?> aClass) {
    return new ArgTranslator() {
      @Override
      public Object translate(String arg) {
        return "Real translation " + arg;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

And my test class is annotated with `@RunWith(JMockit.class)`

```
@Test
  public void testTranslatorFactory() {
    new MockUp<TranslatorFactory>() {
      public ArgTranslator getTranslator(Class<?> baseClass) {
        return new MockUp<ArgTranslator>() {
          public Object translate(String arg) {
            return "Fake translation " + arg;
          }
        }.getMockInstance();
      }
    };

    assertEquals("Fake translation something", new TranslatorFactory().getTranslator(String
        .class).translate("something"));
  }
```

But I just dont seem to get this working. The test always fails. (Running in IntelliJ)

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :Fake translation something
Actual   :Real translation something
```

Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If both `TranslatorFactory` and `ArgTranslator` have all their methods faked, what's left to be tested? I can't see the point of the test.

Comment: The above is not my actual test. I am just seeing if jmockit works as document.

Comment: I saw your response in google groups. I see I was missing @Mock annotations. works now. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe include the answer given on Google Groups so everybody can see it here too @Rogério